# Is it possible to make a global tool from a .Net Framework project?

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, packaging

I've recently [created a command-line tool](https://github.com/mansellan/clickonce) to create ClickOnce packages at the command line. This makes use of [Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core/) to create the application and deployment manifest files. Unfortunately, it also introduces a requirement to target .Net Framework, as the .Net Core version of this package does not contain the [ApplicationManifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.tasks.deployment.manifestutilities.applicationmanifest?view=netframework-4.8) and [DeployManifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.tasks.deployment.manifestutilities.deploymanifest?view=netframework-4.8)  objects necessary to generate the ClickOnce XML files.

I'd love to package my application as a global tool, and publish it to NuGet. Unfortunately, this is only possible for .Net Core assemblies. When I try to pack my project as a tool (by adding `<PackAsTool>true</PackAsTool>`), I get `error NETSDK1054: only supports .NET Core.`

So I think I have three options:

1. Forget about publishing a global tool to NuGet
2. Remove the dependency on `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core`, and just construct the 2 XML files from scratch
3. Create a .Net Core command-line application which does nothing but pass StdIo through to the .Net Framework application, and package the both as a global tool.

I'd like to avoid option 2 if possible, as the XML schemas are non-trivial, and hand-rolling the XML could be a major source of bugs.

I'm not sure if option 3 is appropriate, it would (if it worked) mean publishing a NuGet global tool which had a hidden dependency on .Net Framework - this might be considered bad form.

Have I missed any options?

Answer (score 1):

Given the amount of time elapsed, I think the answer must be 1.

I think the right way to do this is to make a standalone UI, packaged with a traditional installer, which has a command-line interface available for those who wish to use it.